# How to Observe 'add to cart' multiple option of a product

Tags: php, jquery, css, magento, cart

I am new to Magento.I have extended core module Mage: checkout/cart to add to cart with multiple options of product. How can I use the observer with the following event : **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add**

My code:

`config.xml`

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers>
                <flycart_disable_shopping_cart_page>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>flycart/observer</class>
                    <method>cartAdd</method>
                </flycart_disable_shopping_cart_page>
            </observers> 
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

file Observer.php

```
    <?php   class Custom_Flycart_Model_Observer{    
public function cartAdd(){
    // CODE Here    }
        }?>
```

How to can I get multiple product in array post: This is post

[image]

I don't know how to use observers in the Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` in our Observer.php file

It will return array of all parameters sent to called controller's action

Hope this helps you

Comment: yes,i know it but i don't know how to add to cart my option product. I need a concrete example. do you help me.

Comment: Magento default add option in that, my i know why you want custom add ?

Comment: i have product with color black and navy, when customer check and input qty both opiton color => 2 version of product will add to cart. a need observer do it. Now it add only first option. :(